# limsup of the intersection of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $ A_n  $ and $ B_n$ are subsets of $\Omega$.   Can someone show me where I am making a mistake. I saw on here that $\left(\limsup_n A_n\right) \cap \left(\limsup_n B_n\right) \supseteq \limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$ but when I'm trying to prove this I am coming up with equality. Heres my attempt.

Suppose $ \omega \in  \limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$ $ \Rightarrow $ $\omega \in A_{n_k} \cap B_{n_k} $ for all $ k \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow \omega \in A_{n_k} \;$and $\;  \omega \in B_{n_k} \; \forall \; k \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow \omega \in \left(\limsup_n A_n\right) \cap \left(\limsup_n B_n\right)$

Now suppose $ \omega \in \left(\limsup_n A_n\right) \cap \left(\limsup_n B_n\right) \Rightarrow (?)\; \omega \in A_{n_k} $ and  $ \omega \in b_{n_k} \; \forall \;k\in\mathbb N \Rightarrow \omega \in  A_{n_k} \cap B_{n_k} \; \forall \; k \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow \omega \in  \omega \in  \limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$

I think the mistake comes where I put the question mark and I think its because there needs to be two independent subsequences $A_{n_k}$ and $B_{n_{j'}}$ where $  \omega$ happens infinitely often. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve correctly identified the error. Here’s an example to go with it. Let

$$A_n=\begin{cases}
\{0\},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\{1\},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$B_n=\begin{cases}
\{1\},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\{0\},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $A_n\cap B_n=\varnothing$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\limsup_n(A_n\cap B_n)=\varnothing$, but you can easily check that

$$\limsup_nA_n=\{0,1\}=\limsup_nB_n\;.$$